# Can two conditions be given for python's string.split function?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

I have a program where I am parsing a file by each line and splitting it into two half.  After that for each half I am parsing each word from the line and appending it in a list.

Here mfcList1 is a list of lines from a text file. I am parsing each word in the line that are either separated by a comma or by a space. But it isn't exactly working.

```
for lines in mfcList1:
        lines = lines.lstrip()
        if lines!='':
            p.append(string.split(lines,','or " "))
mfcList2 = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,p)

print mfcList2
```

When i am using string.split it is working with only those elements who end with a comma it is ignoring the **or** operator I am using with split method. I want to slice off each and everyword from the line. They either end with a comma or with a space.

for eg. '**enableEmergencySpare=1 useGlobalSparesForEmergency=1 useUnconfGoodForEmergency=1**',

this line is being stored as a single list element where as I am trying to split them using split method..

Can anyone pls suggest what i can do instead of using or operator... thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()` from the `re` module:

```
import re
...
p.extend(re.split('[ ,]', lines))
```

The `[ ,]` is a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) which means "a space or a comma". Also, assuming `p` is a list and you want to add all the words to it, you should use `extend()` rather than `append()`, the latter adds a single element.

Note also that if a line in the file contains command followed by space (or other sequence of commas and spaces) your list `p` will contain a corresponding number of empty strings.

Comment: it didn't display the output in the list format. I want the output as a list..it just showed output as words separated by spaces but not a as a list.

Comment: Well, yes, because you combine all the elements of the list with `reduce()`. If you don't want to do it, then don't call `reduce()` and instead just display the list populated in the loop (i.e. `p`).

Comment: it is still printing the same thing. it is taking only ,                        enableEmergencySpare=1 useGlobalSparesForEmergency=1 useUnconfGoodForEmergency=1

Comment: i think i got it now.. thanks for the solution