# Trying to split a string

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

I have a small syntax problem. I have a string and another string that has a list of seperators. I need to split it via the `.split` method.

I can't seem to figure out how, this certainly gives a Type error.

```
String.split([' ', '{', '='])
```

How can i split it with multiple seperators?

Comment: show us input and expected output to get the answer you want from us

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.rsplit) only accepts one separator.

Use [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split) to split using a regular expression.

```
import re

re.split(r"[ {=]", "foo bar=baz{qux")
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the built-in `split()` method works. It simply uses a single string as the separator, not a list of single-character separators.

You can use [regular-expression based](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) splitting, instead. This would probably mean building a regular expression that is the "or" of all your desired delimiters:

```
splitters = "|".join([" ", "{", "="])
re.split(splitters, my_string)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work just like that. `re.escape` may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `re` (regex) library like so:

```
import re
result=re.split("[abc]", "my string with characters i want to split")
```

Where the characters in the square brackets are the characters you want to split with.

Answer (score 0):

Use split from regular expressions instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'toto + titi = tata'
>>> re.split('[+=]', s)
['toto ', ' titi ', ' tata']
>>>
```

Comment: Your reqular expression is missing the space ` `.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string_test = "abc cde{fgh=ijk"
re.split('[\s{=]',string_test)
```

Comment: The OP didn't include *every* whitespace and bars `|` in the list of his delimiters.