# Django to store group of words in array and displays one by one

Tags: python, django

I need to get input from user and stored it in array. For Example, if user input is like `python,Html,css` or `python html css` or `python/html/css`. I have to stored it in array like `a[0]=python; a[1]=html; a[2]=css;` it should neglect comma(,) and whitespaces and slash(/)

Comment: It will be really nice if you try to do this by yourself first.

Comment: I don't know how to stored so that I posted this question. If you know answer me please.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to simply process a string into a list with multiple delimiters. A quick search revealed another similar StackOverflow question which may lead to an answer.

You might be able to accomplish what you're looking for with the "`re.split()`" function.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998688/1011998