# Python : splitting string with multiple characters

Tags: python

I have a following input :

```
"auth-server $na me$ $1n ame$ [position [$pr io$]] xxxx [match-fqdn [[$fq dn$] [all]]]"
```

I need to store them in a list with `$`, `<`, and `>` serving as delimiters.

Expected output:

```
['auth-server', '$na me$', '$1n ame$', '[position', '[$pr io$]]', 'xxxx', '[match-fqdn', '[[$fq dn$]', '[all]]]']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry input is :"auth-server $1n ame$ [position []] xxxx [match-fqdn [[] [all]]]"

Comment: You can always edit your post, that's better than adding comments. Indent a line by four spaces to turn off formatting for that line.

Comment: I edited your post to format the code for you. If I lost any meaning, don't hesitate to [edit] your post again to fix it.

Comment: do you mean `[` or `]` as opposed to `<` or `>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: Thanks for formatting to see properly thats what i meant

Comment: You have nested delimiters here. Python doesn't support recursive regexes, that will make things difficult...

Comment: @farmerjoe , $ can be replaced with < > , there was some problem while entering the question , so i changed to $ , we can always extend to < > once we do for $

Comment: @thegrinner - its similar to what you refereed but the delimiter should also be present especially $ in the list

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is split it on the spaces, then go through each substring and check if it starts with one of the special delimiters. If it does, start a new string and append subsequent strings until you get to the end delimiter. Then remove those substrings and replace them with the new one.

Comment: What you meant is: words = a.split() ? and then traverse the list again for delimiter ? 
where a = "auth-server $na me$ $1n ame$ [position [$pr io$]] xxxx [match-fqdn [[$fq dn$] [all]]]"
am i right ?

Comment: The traversal would be over the "words" list. You'll want to use a second list ("words2") and a temporary string when creating the new specially delimited substring.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
import re
re.split(r"(?<=\]) | (?=\$|\[)", "auth-server $na me$ $1n ame$ [position [$pr io$]] xxxx [match-fqdn [[$fq dn$] [all]]]")
```

This yields

```
['auth-server', '$na me$', '$1n ame$', '[position', '[$pr io$]]', 'xxxx', '[match-fqdn', '[[$fq dn$]', '[all]]]']
```

Note however that this is not exactly what you described, but what matches your example. It seems that you want to split on spaces when they are preceded by `]` or followed by `$` or `[`.

Comment: Thanks i want something like this.

Answer (score 1):

try re.split and a regex who make someone cry blood

```
import re
print re.split(r'(\$[^\$]+\$|\[\S+([^\]]+\]\])?|[-0-9a-zA-Z]+)',"auth-server $na me$ $1n ame$ [position [$pr io$]] xxxx [match-fqdn [[$fq dn$] [all]]]")
```

Answer (score 1):

consider using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing):

```
from pyparsing import *
enclosed = Forward()
nestedBrackets = nestedExpr('[', ']') 
enclosed << ( Combine(Group(Optional('$') + Word(alphas) + Optional('$'))) | nestedBrackets )
print enclosed.parseString(data).asList()
```

output:

```
[['auth-server', '$na', 'me$', '$1n', 'ame$', ['position', ['$pr', 'io$']], 'xxxx', 
 ['match-fqdn', [['$fq', 'dn$'], ['all']]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a full answer, but I used `regexp` search...

```
a = "auth-server $na me$ $1n ame$ [position [$pr io$]] xxxx [match-fqdn [[$fq dn$] [all]]]"
m = re.search('\$.*\$', a)
```

combine this with `a.split()` and we can do the math...