# Splitting strings in a series when a number is encountered in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a series of strings in a dataframe, and I want to get rid of everything in the string once a number starts. Here's an example:

```
sstrings['abc12390859', 'def1959836', 'dab3496876', 'gh34643267']
```

so, in the end, I want it to be:

```
sstrings['abc', 'def', 'dab', 'gh']
```

I thought about doing something like:

```
df['sstrings'] = df['sstrings'].str.split()
```

but since the leading number isn't always the same, I'm not sure how to make that work.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters) but that doesn't seem to work with a series.

Is there a way to do this without looping through the series and using `re.split`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression. Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['abc12390859', 'def1959836', 'dab3496876', 'gh34643267']    
>>> ss = [re.match(r'[^\d]+', x).group(0) for x in s]
>>> ss
['abc', 'def', 'dab', 'gh']
```

Explanation:

`\d` matches any digit.
`[^\d]` matches anything that is not a digit
`[^\d]+` matches a sequence of one or more non-digits.

The documentation for `re.match` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). It will return a `MatchObject` (from which we extract the matching string with `group`)  if zero or more characters at the beginning of the string match our pattern `[^\d]+`. `re.match` is applied to all `x` in your original list `s` with a list comprehension.

Comment: That works! Thanks. Can you explain the code for it?

Comment: @PointXIV certainly, is it enough to explain the regular expression, or do you need an explanation for list comprehensions too?

Comment: Tip: you can use `s.str.extract()` to do this directly on a pandas Series: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html

Comment: just the regular expression is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case, the final part of each string consists only from numbers, you can use:

```
>>> lst = ['abc12390859', 'def1959836', 'dab3496876', 'gh34643267']
>>> map(lambda txt: txt.rstrip("0123456789"), lst)
['abc', 'def', 'dab', 'gh']
```

or using list comprehension:

```
>>> [txt.rstrip("0123456789") for txt in  lst]
['abc', 'def', 'dab', 'gh']
```