# Using Python to split long string, by given ‘separators’

Tags: python

Environment: Win 7; Python 2.76

I want to split a long string into pieces, according to given `separator`

The string looks like:

```
“C-603WallWizard45256CCCylinders:2HorizontalOpposedBore:1-1/42006Stroke:1-1/8Length: SingleVerticalBore:1-111Height:6Width:K-720Cooling:AirWeight:6LBS1.5H.P.@54500RPMC-60150ccGas2007EngineCylinder:4VerticalInline2008Bore:1Stroke:1Cycle:42007Weight:6-1/2LBSLength:10Width: :AirLength16Cooling:AirLength:5Width:4L-233Height:6Weight: 4TheBlackKnightc-609SteamEngineBore:11/16Stroke:11/162008Length:3Width:3Height:4TheChallengerC-600Bore:1Stroke:1P-305Weight:18LBSLength:12Width:7Height:8C-606Wall15ccGasEngineJ-142Cylinder:SingleVerticalBore:1Stroke:1-1/8Cooling:1Stroke:1-1/4HP:: /4Stroke:1-7/:6Width:6Height:92006Weight:4LBS1.75H.P.@65200RPM”
```

The `separator` are: `[‘2006’, ‘2007’, ‘2008’, ‘2009’]`

How is it possible to achieve?

### Update

I've checked the post [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-delimiters) before however I don't think the need is the same as the post is about how to split a string  into words. Mine's above is a split according to elements in a list.

Comment: This is not necessary a trivial question **if** the string is **very long**.

Comment: Is Google broken? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify some things: how long is the string ?  would you split on any occurrence of `2006`, `2007`, etc. Are the "newline" part of your string ?

Comment: Although the marked duplicate is the canonical answer, you might find the answers to [this other duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters) more immediately useful to you.

Comment: Also, if your question is "I want these separators exactly once, in exactly this order", then the question is _not_ a duplicate, so please edit your question to make that clear so it can be reopened.

Comment: thanks, Sylvain Leroux and abarnert.

Comment: @abarnert It doesn't seem to be about the order since `2007` appears before and after `2008`.

Comment: @MarkK: "I've checked the post Python strings split with multiple delimiters before": This is exactly why SO keeps dups around, and shows them in Linked on the canonical question. It may be not at all obvious to a novice that your question is the same as the original, but if you look at some of the linked questions there (like the one I linked above), it's a lot more obvious. For example, kLeos wanted to split on any `,` or `;`, just like you want to split on any `2006`, `2007`, `2008`, or `2009`. And now your question appears on the links too, which may help other future searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split by any instance of any of those separators, you may want a regular expression:

```
r = re.compile(r'|'.join(separators))
r.split(s)
```

Note that this is not a safe way to build regexps in general; it only works here because I know that none of your separators contain any special characters. If you don't know that for sure, use `re.escape`:

```
r = re.compile(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, separators)))
```

---

If you want to split by those separators exactly once each, in exactly that order, you probably want to use either `str.split` or `str.partition`:

```
bits = []
for separator in separators:
    first, _, s = s.partition(separator)
    bits.append(first)
bits.append(s)
```

Comment: dear abarnert, thank you indeed. I am amazed always by what it can do. your help and guidance is very important in my learning. thank you again.