# how to get values from a list that are like values in a set in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a set with values like `(20140101224466, 20140209226655, ...)`, 
and I have a list that contains `('abcde.test.20140101224466', rbtd.test.20140209226655)`.

How would I compare my list against the set to get only the values in the list that contain the values in the set? Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, is your "set" a true Python set, a list, or a tuple? Your notation is rather confusing...

Answer (score 1):

```
test_set = {20140101224466, 20140209226655, ... }
test_list = ['abcde.test.20140101224466', 'rbtd.test.20140209226655']

solution = [value for value in test_list if int(value.split('.')[-1]) in test_set]
```

Comment: I think this will work but is it possible to split with multiple delimeters  like value.split('. _')  ?

Comment: @JoshQL you can split with multiple delimiters using regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters. You would `import re` and then replace `int(value.split('.')[-1])` with `int(re.split('.|_', value)[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
set1 = {20140101224466, 20140209226655}
list2 = ['abcde.test.20140101224466', 'rbtd.test.20140209226655']

print [i for i in list2 if int(i.split('.')[-1]) in set1]
# ['rbtd.test.20140209226655', 'abcde.test.20140101224466']
```