# Splitting a column into multiple ones

Tags: python, split, multiple-columns

I have a data with multiple values summarized in one column like (much more rows):

```
"(-99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0)"                                                            
"(0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563, 0.43963563)"
"(0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014, 0.20000014)"
```

Now my goal is to get rid of the `'"'`, `'('` and `')'` and, which is the more important part, to split each row into 12 columns to finally get something like this:

```
      1         2            3          4          5           6             7            8          9         10           11         12
-99            -99          -99       -99         -99         -99          -99          -99         -99         -99        -99        -99
0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563  0.43963563
0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014  0.20000014
```

All I've got so far is some code to split my rows into separate values and to get rid of the `','`:

```
my_file = open("expand_single_column_alternate.dat","r")
content = my_file.read()
liste = content.split(",")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python strings split with multiple delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/python-strings-split-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to constrain my question a little bit, after I tried some things out.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, where each line is actually a valid Python tuple holding multiple numbers, you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to turn the line into an actual tuple:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 )"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```