# How to split a string based on either a colon or a hyphen?

Tags: python, string, split

```
a = '4-6'
b= '7:10'
```

I have already tried

```
a.split('-')
a.split(':')
```

how can i write code that can take in either string and get rid of both colons and hyphens? Is there a better way besides splitting the same string twice?

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of all elements seperated by either a '-' or ':'. Or just remove those characters from the string and return the new string sans thats character?

Comment: Duplicate of many different questions. The one marked and [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To split on more than one delimiter, you can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and a character set:

```
import re
re.split('[-:]', a)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '4-6'
>>> b = '7:10'
>>> re.split('[-:]', a)
['4', '6']
>>> re.split('[-:]', b)
['7', '10']
```

Note however that `-` is also used to specify a range of characters in a character set.  For example, `[A-Z]` will match all uppercase letters.  To avoid this behavior, you can put the `-` at the start of the set as I did above. For more information on Regex syntax, see [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the docs.

Comment: You should mention that this is called a regular expression.

Comment: I think regular expressions should be avoided in the case of beginners.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi - Why?  In my opinion, they are a very useful tool that every programmer should be aware of.  Now that's not to say they should be used *everywhere*, but in this case, a Regex solution is nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace one by the other then split the entire string:

```
parts = your_string.replace('-', ':').split(':')
```

Comment: This seems like a clean hack but somehow I feel like we're missing something 