# Python regex for logical operators

Tags: python, regex

I am developing a rule system which can accept relational and logical operators.

A simple expression in the rule system could be as simple as

`EmployeeAgeProperty >= IntegerProperty:27`

where I define what would substitute the `EmployeeHireDateProperty` and my rulesystem will evaluate that. Assume that each simple expression like above would evaluate to a true/false. My regex for this would be

`(?P<lhs>[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*Property):{0,1}(?P<lhsPrimitiveValue>[A-Za-z0-9]*)\ *(?P<operator>[><=]|!=|<=|>=|in|not_in)\ *(?P<rhs>[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*Property):{0,1}(?P<rhsPrimitiveValue>[A-Za-z0-9]*)`

lhs = Left Hand Side 
rhs = Right Hand side.

Now, I want to combine number of simple expressions into compound expressions via logical operators And/Or(lets assume Not is out of context).

So, a valid  compound expression would be

`SimpleExpression1 and SimpleExpression2 or SimpleExpression3`
where each simple expression inturn would match the above regex.

I want my regex group to return `('SimpleExpression1', 'and', SimpleExpression2', 'or', 'SimpleExpression3')`

I could comeup with something like this

`([\w\d!=< ]*)\ *(and|or)\ *([\w\d!=< ]*)` which would match a single compound expression with one and/or. But couldn't able to expand further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to try `re.split`, see also [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

```
re.split('(and|or)', 'this and this or that')
Out[18]: ['this ', 'and', ' this ', 'or', ' that']
```

Comment: Ha ha, that actually would work for my problem :-) Are there any regex solns available ? Mainly I am interested to see what I've missed.

Comment: hmm not sure, to be honest i don't really like complicated regex's , i find them so hard to read and maintain, i'd much prefer a simpler solution with readable steps.