# Python extract lines in specific section of SQL script

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of stored procedure scripts from sql server that I'd like to extract the custom coding section from.  The area I'd like to grab is preceded by this:

```
/* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* * Begin Custom Code ******************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
```

and followed by this:

```
/* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* * End Custom Code ********************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
```

So the script would look like:

```
/* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* * Begin Custom Code ******************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */

    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM [dbo].[table1]
    ORDER BY col1

    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* * End Custom Code ********************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
```

Is there a way to read the file and write the lines in between those markers to a separate file as one long string (no tabs or line breaks)?

Comment: Are there multiple `Begin Custom Code` blocks in a file or only one?

Comment: One approach might be to `split` on both `/*` and `*/` and pick the element(s) of the resulting list that doesn't start with `/*`

Comment: @dstudeba: Only one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can read the text in yourself, you might do something like this:

(Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998655/2071807))

```
chunks = sql.replace('/*', '*/').split('*/')
relevant = [x for x in chunks if not x.startswith('/*')
```

Comment: Oops. My split on multiple conditions doesn't work, I don't think. If someone can fix it, this answer will make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea

```
inputArray = inputFile.split('*/')
for val in inputArray:
    if not val.strip().startswith('/*'):
        print(val.strip().split("\n").join(" "))
```

Comment: HAHA!  Sorry I have been working on PHP recently, I was just fixing it after I realized my mistake.  You caught me first!

Answer (score 0):

Read each line and do strip on it. If the resulting line is empty or starts with '/*' skip and read next line. Ohterwise append to a list.

```
sql = '''/* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* * Begin Custom Code ******************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */

    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM [dbo].[table1]
    ORDER BY col1

    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* * End Custom Code ********************************************************************************************************************************** */
    /* **************************************************************************************************************************************************** */
'''
lines = []
for line in sql.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line or line.startswith('/*'):
        continue
    lines.append(line)

' '.join(lines)

'SELECT col1, col2 FROM [dbo].[table1] ORDER BY col1'
```

Using regex;

```
' '.join(line.strip() for line in re.sub(r'/\*.*?\*/','',sql,flags=re.DOTALL).strip().splitlines())
```

'SELECT col1, col2 FROM [dbo].[table1] ORDER BY col1'