# Python split string that have two delimited

Tags: python, string, split

I want to know how to split a string with more then one delimiter. I have a problem splitting if one is space?

I trying to read a text file that has this:

> 22.0;2016-01-16 00:16:18

I know how to read a text file to a variable, but when I have problem to split even a string I can't go further.

All I have now is this code:

```
with open('datasource_3.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     for line in data:
         words = line.strip().split(';')
    print words
```

Comment: What is your expected output? This is critical information!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: yes sorry I forgot about it
['21.7', '2016-01-15 23:33:54']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split with the [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) `;|`, like so:

```
import re

x = '22.0;2016-01-16 00:16:18'
print re.split(';| ', x)
```

This prints `['22.0', '2016-01-16', '00:16:18']`.

Comment: Thank you it works greate
I  did just add .strip() to make it work like I want to THANKS

Comment: No problem! You can add, e.g., `;| |,|-` to the regex if you want to recognize more delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
>>> x = "22.0;2016-01-16 00:16:18"
>>> x.strip().split(';')
['22.0', '2016-01-16 00:16:18']
>>> y = [word.split(' ') for word in x.split(';')]
>>> y
[['22.0'], ['2016-01-16', '00:16:18']]
>>> [item for sublist in y for item in sublist]
['22.0', '2016-01-16', '00:16:18']
```

This is the equivalent of splitting your initial input, then splitting each result on your second delimiter. Finally, you ['flatten' the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python).

As a one-liner, this is what you're looking for:

```
[item for sublist in [word.split(' ') for word in x.strip().split(';')] for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Now add the `re` one liner. :)

Comment: it's very verbose solution for such a simple task

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` can be of help here

```
import itertools

s = '22.0;2016-01-16 00:16:18'

sp = itertools.chain(*([x] if not i else x.split(' ')
                       for i, x in enumerate(s.split(';'))))

print(list(sp))
```

Output:

```
['22.0', '2016-01-16', '00:16:18']
```

With a potentially more elegant `or` (instead of `if`) syntax:

```
sp = itertools.chain(*([x] * (not i) or x.split(' ') for i, x in enumerate(s.split(';'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shlex to create your own parser:

```
import shlex

def split_multi(_str, delims="", ws=True):
    parser = shlex.shlex(_str, posix=True)
    parser.whitespace_split = ws
    parser.whitespace += delims
    return pars
```

Demo:

```
In [15]: sh = split_multi(s, ";")

In [16]: list(sh)
Out[16]: ['22.0', '2016-01-16', '00:16:18']
```