# Python split with multiple delimiters not working

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, split

I have a string:

feature.append(freq_and_feature(text, freq))

I want a list containing each word of the string, like [feature, append, freq, and, feature, text, freq], where each word is a string, of course.

These string are contained in a file called helper.txt, so I'm doing the following, as suggested by multiple SO posts, like the accepted answer for this one([Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)):

```
import re
with open("helper.txt", "r") as helper:
    for row in helper:

       print re.split('\' .,()_', row)
```

However, I get the following, which is not what I want.

```
['    feature.append(freq_pain_feature(text, freq))\n']
```

Comment: Probably because the string described by the pattern doesn't exist. read a tutorial before, ask after.

Comment: The first argument to `re.split()` must be a correct [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) that matches the delimiter.  It is not a string where any character is a single-character delimiter.

Comment: Can I do this instead with the regular str.split(), then?

Comment: Usually I just split by space characters so I'm not quite sure how to do this (split by multiple delimiters).

Comment: Are you just going to split with non-word and non-underscore characters? Try [this solution](http://ideone.com/WpyPvU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> re.split('\' .,()_', row)
> ```

This looks for the string `' .,()_` to split on. You probably meant

```
re.split('[\' .,()_]', row)
```

`re.split` takes a *regular expression* as the first argument. To say "this OR that" in regular expressions, you can write `a|b` and it will match either `a` or `b`. If you wrote `ab`, it would only match `a` followed by `b`. Luckily, so we don't have to write `'| |.|,|(|...`, there's a nice form where you can use `[]`s to state that everything inside should be treated as "match one of these".

Comment: Okay, when I do what you suggested, I get the following: ['', '', '', '', 'feature', 'append', 'freq', 'and', 'feature', 'text', '', 'freq', '', '\n']

Comment: this works, but needs a + added to prevent the empty strings in your results:[\' .,()_]+

Comment: Oh I see. This indeed works and is what I ended up using. Thanks.

Comment: @Jobs If this is what you used, perhaps you should accept it. But if another answer helped you more, please accept that.

Comment: Accepting this one because this was the first answer and so what I ended up using. All of the answers are very informative - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to split a string with non-word or underscore characters. Use

```
import re
s = 'feature.append(freq_and_feature(text, freq))'
print([x for x in re.split(r'[\W_]+', s) if x])
# => ['feature', 'append', 'freq', 'and', 'feature', 'text', 'freq']
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WpyPvU)

The `[\W_]+` regex matches 1+ characters that are not word (`\W` = `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or underscores.

You can get rid of the `if x` if you remove initial and trailing non-word characters from the input string, e.g. `re.sub(r'^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$', '', s)`.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to split on the basis of `non-word` characters. It should be

```
re.split(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', s)
```

**`[^A-Za-z0-9]` can be translated to --> `[\W_]`**

*Python Code*

```
s = 'feature.append(freq_and_feature(text, freq))'
print([x for x in re.split(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', s) if x])
```

This will also work, indeed

```
p = re.compile(r'[^\W_]+')
test_str = "feature.append(freq_and_feature(text, freq))"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/vEvBnY)**

Comment: @Jobs You can use `re.findall()` too for this

Answer (score 1):

### You can try this

```
str = re.split('[.(_,)]+', row, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
str.pop()
print str
```

This will result:

```
['feature', 'append', 'freq', 'and', 'feature', 'text', ' freq']
```