# Dividing into sentences based on pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to divide a text into sentences based on a delimiter in python. However, I do not want to split them based on decimal points between numbers, or comma between numbers. How do we ignore them.

For example, I have a text like below.

```
I am xyz.I have 44.44$. I would like, to give 44,44 cents to my friend.
```

The sentences has to be

```
I am xyz
I have 44.44$
I would like
to give 44,44 cents to my friend
```

Could you please help me with the regular expression. I am sorry if this question has already been asked before. I could not find it.

Thank you

Comment: Similar question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters

Comment: What regular expression did you try? What are the sentences found by this regular expression?

Comment: import nltk;sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle');sent_detector.tokenize(s)

Comment: You may try [`re.split(r'\s*[.,](?!\d)\s*', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/m9wfUN/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for your example, although there's a trailing full stop (period) on the last part if that matters.

```
import re

s = 'I am xyz. I have 44.44$. I would like, to give 44,44 cents to my friend.'

for part in re.split('[.,]\s+', s):
    print(part)
```

**Output**

```
I am xyz
I have 44.44$
I would like
to give 44,44 cents to my friend.
```

---

Wiktor's expression `\s*[.,](?!\d)\s` will work for your new example:

```
I am xyz.I have 44.44$. I would like, to give 44,44 cents to my friend.
```

Breaking this down:

- `\s*` will match 0 to many whitespace characters.
- `[.,]` will match either a `,` or a `.` character.
- `(?!\d)` will cause the match to be discarded if a digit is matched at this point. This is necessary to avoid splitting within numbers.
- `\s` will match a single whitespace character.

Note that it will still fail for sentences like "I am 22.10 years ago I was 12.", though I don't think there's any way to get around that using regular expressions alone.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not give a proper example then. The regex which you have given will not work for   I am xyz.I have 44.44$. I would like, to give 44,44 cents to my friend.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!!