# Split python string with multiple delimiter

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a python string `line = '1 -1 2 3 -1 4'` so that my output is a python list`['1','2','3','4']`. I tried solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters). However, some strange output is coming. My code:

```
line = '1 -1 2 3 -1 4'
import re    
t=re.split("-1| ", line)
```

output:

```
['1', '', '', '2', '3', '', '', '4']
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a tricky one :)

```
re.split(r"(?:\s-1)?\s",line)
#['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

And the fastest solution (runs about 4.5 times faster than the regex):

```
line.replace("-1 ", "").split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
t=re.split("\s+",line.replace("-1"," "))
```

Comment: I had that sol is mind. How about time complexity of the above code or Can we do that without replacing -1 by space?

Comment: Yes I would imagine it's not the most efficient of possible solutions.  Would have to do some timing tests.

Comment: The replace with space appears to be consistently faster by 3-4 times - but the reader should probably do his/her own timing tests to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too with lookahead:

```
print re.findall('(?<=[^-])\d+', ' ' +line)
# ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

This is more generic since this will filter out all negative numbers.

```
line = '-10 12 -10 20 3 -2 40 -5 5 -1 1' 
print re.findall('(?<=[^-\d])\d+', ' ' +line)
# ['12', '20', '3', '40', '5', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using a regex but a conditional list comprehension:

```
>>> line = '1 -1 2 3 -1 4'
>>> [substr for substr in line.split() if not substr.startswith('-')]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   line.replace(' -1','').split(' ')
   # ['1','2','3','4'].
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't say whether this would be more efficient than some of the other solutions, but a list comprehension is very readable and could certainly do the trick:

```
line = '1 -1 2 3 -1 4'
t = [str(item) for item in line.split(" ") if int(item) >= 0]
>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: What about 0's?