# Is split() function changed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Split function on official python site is as 
`split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)`

But when I check it on spyder it is `split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`

Is string argument removed from split() function in python 3.6?

If not then why can't I pass a string arg in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first `split` is from the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
```

The second is a [`str` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
```

The way you call the `str.split` method is off a `str` object like the following

```
>>> s = 'this is a string'
>>> s.split(' ')
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```

Comment: How can I use re module and if I want to pass more than one delimiter in str's split() then how can I achieve it?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters) should answer both of those questions. So will [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: It means in str.split() we are limited with only one delimiter. Am I right. because all the answers used re module.