# `re.split()` in Python working strangely

Tags: python, split

Having a bit of a predicament in python.  I'd like to take a .txt file with many comments and split it into a list.  However, I'd like to split on all punctuation, spaces and \n.  When I run the following python code, it splits my text file in weird spots.
NOTE: Below I am only trying to split on periods and endlines to test it out.  But it is still often getting rid of the last letter in words.

```
import regex as re
with open('G:/My Documents/AHRQUnstructuredComments2.txt','r') as infile:
    nf = infile.read()
    wList = re.split('. | \n, nf)

print(wList)
```

Comment: You forgot a closing quote for the regex string.

Comment: See if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters

Comment: I dunno why it did that in this snippet of code, I have it there in my ipynb file

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the quote marks and make a slight change to the regular expression:

```
import regex as re
with open('G:/My Documents/AHRQUnstructuredComments2.txt','r') as infile:
    nf = infile.read()
    wList = re.split('\W+' nf)

print(wList)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but do you know of a site that will tell me how the escape sequences work in the .split() function? I think because I'm trying to remove punctuation and special characters and I'm not properly describing them.

Comment: @JohnW Escape characters will allow the following character to be matched by itself in the expression. Otherwise, the character takes on a special meaning. Regarding the split function, the expression passed to it remains the same for all re methods. See here for more info regarding escape characters: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the string and you need \ before .

```
import regex as re
with open('G:/My Documents/AHRQUnstructuredComments2.txt','r') as infile:
    nf = infile.read()
    wList = re.split('\. |\n |\s', nf)

print(wList)
```

See [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters) for more info.

Also, RichieHindle answers your question perfectly:

```
import re
DATA = "Hey, you - what are you doing here!?"
print re.findall(r"[\w']+", DATA)
# Prints ['Hey', 'you', 'what', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'here']
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that out.  It's really useful to see why the Python interpreter is doing the things it does sometimes

Comment: Yeah, as intuitive as python is it can sometimes be tricky, hope everything ends up working for you!

Answer (score 2):

In regex, the character `.` means *any character*. You have to escape it, `\.`, to capture periods.

Comment: Thank you! Will experiment with this!