# I have some problems about lists Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, list, append

Could you tell me what's wrong here?

For some reason there's nothing added into the list.

```
textarea = raw_input()
n=0
txa = []
string =""

while(n < len(textarea)):
    if(textarea[n] != ' ' or textarea[n] != ','):

        string += textarea[n]
        n=n+1
        print (string)

    else:
        print "For some reason I'm never here."

        if(string == ' ' or string == ','):
            string = ""
        else:
            txa.append(string)
            string = ""
            n=n+1
print(txa)
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That is important to understand to help you better.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry

I'm trying to make a list from a string...

Like: "Hello, goodbye"

Then, txa would be like: ['Hello', 'goodbye']

I'm sorry for my poor explanation...

Comment: What's wrong with `re.split()`?

Comment: Well, I'm just a badass, I didn't know about that, thank you xD

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `or` in your if statement to an `and`. Currently the condition is always true because it is impossible for `textarea[n]` to be both ' ' and ','.

You can also use regular expressions to split the string as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> txt = "Hello, goodbye Fred"
>>> txt.replace(',', ' ').split()
['Hello', 'goodbye', 'Fred']
```

Comment: Hey, I was trying with your code, I'm sure it works perfectly, but I'm a bit idiot, so I couldn't get it to work.

Anyway, I solved with: `"textarea.split(", ")"`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change `or` in your 1st `if` with `and`.

Second, `if-else` block in the 1st `else` is redundant. Try deleting it, but retaining the code in the 2nd `else` block.

Third, add an `append` just after the `while` so that the last word that is stored in the `string` variable also gets into the `txa` list.

Your code will pretty much, look like this -

```
while(n < len(textarea)):
    if(textarea[n] != ' ' and textarea[n] != ','):
        string += textarea[n]
        n=n+1
        print (string)

    else:
        print ("For some reason I'm never here.")
        txa.append(string)
        string = ""
        n=n+1

txa.append(string)
print(txa)
```

Tip: Moreover, you can try using in-built functions to do splitting for you.

```
txa = str(raw_input()).replace(',', ' ').split()
```

This one-liner works just fine.

Comment: That moment when I feel like a idiot... Python is incredible, thank you a lot!