# Dividing the input in python

Tags: input, split

I'm doing a project where I need to insert coordinates in the console to return a place in a grid. My grid is 10*10 and has numbers in the rows and Letters in the columns. 
I want to be able to input something like A1 and for it to be interpreted as "column1, row1"

So far I have got:

```
def get_coor():
    user_input = input("Please enter coordinates (row,col) ? ")
    coor = user_input.split(" ")
    return coor
```

But I'm only able to split if I have a space. Is there any other function to help me in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-with-multiple-delimiters) or [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)

Answer (score 1):

Strings are iterable in Python.

If you write:

```
user_input = input("Please enter coordinates (row,col)?")
<input A1>
```

Then `user_input[0]` will be A and `user_input[1]` will be 1.

Therefore, no need for the split :)
Split is used precisely for the use case when there is a space: it returns a list of all the strings between the occurrences of the character given as an argument (in your case a space).

Comment: If you want the output to be "column1,row1" just `return f"{input[0]},input[1]"`