# How can I split a string with two different spacings?

Tags: python, string

I want to separate some words of a string but there is two types of divisions in the line using python:
Example of the string:

```
add $s2, $s0, $s1
```

I want to separate in:

```
"add", "$s2", "$s0", "$s1"
```

but with `data.split()` function I can only Split them with "," or " ", but in this case between add and $s2 it doesn't have "," only " ".

```
arq = open('entrada.asm', 'r')
text = arq.readlines()
for line in text:
    (inst) = line.split(" ")
    (reg1, reg2, reg3) = line.split(",")
    print(inst, reg1, reg2, reg3)
arq.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split`:

```
import re
re.split('[ ,]+', 'add $s2, $s0, $s1')
```

Output:

```
['add', '$s2', '$s0', '$s1']
```

Comment: Kind of nitpicking, but seemings like `r',? +'` stays truer to the pattern in question