# How to know what separator separated elements in a split?

Tags: python, regex, split, delimiter, separator

In Python, how can I split a string using multiple delimiters and know which delimiter was used to separate any two elements?

E.g. in the following example taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python):

```
>>> a='Beautiful, is; better*than\nugly'
>>> import re
>>> re.split('; |, |\*|\n',a)
['Beautiful', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'ugly']
```

how can I determine that the separator which separated 'is' and 'better' was '; '?

`awk` has a useful way to accomplish this with `patsplit(string, array [, fieldpat [, seps ] ])`, where `seps` is an array that holds the separator that separated two elements.  In this case, `seps[1]` would be ', ', `seps[2]` would be '; ', `seps[3]` would be '*', and `seps[4]` would be '\n'.  I didn't see a similar feature in `re.split`.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the Regex pattern to get the separators in the output:

```
In [16]: a = 'Beautiful, is; better*than\nugly'                                                                                                                                                             

In [17]: re.split(r'(; |, |\*|\n)', a)                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[17]: ['Beautiful', ', ', 'is', '; ', 'better', '*', 'than', '\n', 'ugly']
```

Then you can get the separators with usual index notations.

Now if you want the spitted words, slice from index 0 with a step of 2:

```
In [18]: re.split(r'(; |, |\*|\n)', a)[::2]                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[18]: ['Beautiful', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'ugly']
```

to get the separators, slice from index 1 with a step of 2:

```
In [19]: re.split(r'(; |, |\*|\n)', a)[1::2]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[19]: [', ', '; ', '*', '\n']
```