# Splitting a line of complex string

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I need to split a really complex line for me. The line I want to split is as follows**

`2019.10.20-22.01.33: '10.11.111.25 9999995555884411:TechnoBeceT(69)' logged in`

**how can i split this like this**

`['2019.10.20-22.01.33', '10.11.111.25', '9999995555884411', 'logged in']`

**i don't need**
`TechnoBeceT(69)` **this area**.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try? SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regular Expression

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'(([\d\.-]+)(?::|\s)|(logged in))')

s = "2019.10.20-22.01.33: '10.11.111.25 9999995555884411:TechnoBeceT(69)' logged in"

q = [x[1] or x[2] for x in p.findall(s)]

print(q)
```

Output

```
['2019.10.20-22.01.33', '10.11.111.25', '9999995555884411', 'logged in']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to split by ' ', ':' and 'TechnoBeceT(69)' as an appropriate regex. This existing question is probably what you need: [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)