# How to split a paragraph in to lines using Python libraries

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, analytics

I have a paragraph with some spaces and special characters and "....." 's.

I would like to know if there is any function in python which helps in splitting the lines in the paragraph with specified delimiters like "...."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to do this:

1. `string.split` will return a list of lines and then `string.join` to form the sentences. [split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

```
input = # Your paragraph
input.split('...')  # will return a list of lines
''.join(input) # will return a set of lines
```

2. `regex.split` likewise will return a list of lines (recommended) [regex split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
re.split(r'\.\.\.', input)
```