# How would I be able remove punctuation then split that word into two?

Tags: python

How would I be able to split a word containing punctuation into 2 separate words without punctuation? For example if I have the string "half-attained", how would I make it so that I can remove the "-" as well as splitting the words into "half" and "attained".

This is what I have so far and it only removes the punctuation and puts the words together.

```py
for n in range(0,len(test_list)):
  no_punct = ""
  for char in test_list[n]:
    if char not in punctuations:
        no_punct = no_punct + char
  no_puclist.append(no_punct)
```

Comment: After seeing some of the answers, it might be best if you showed the punctuation string, which I assume has more than one character in it. All of the answers so far have assumed "-" is the only character to split on.

Comment: This question's accepted answer is pretty much what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python

Answer (score 1):

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) returns a list of the words of a string separated along a separator.

In your case:

```py
"half-attained".split("-")  
# ["half", "attained"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`split()` does it well

```
print( "half-attained".split("-")  )

# output :
# ["half", "attained"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) :

```
string = "half-attained"
array = string.split("-")
print(array)
```

> str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) : Return a list of the words in the
>   string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at
>   most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most
>   maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there
>   is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

Comment: You shouldn't name it string as that's also a module name that they might be using

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. But how would i do it so that it uses punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~''' in order for it to check to remove?

Comment: you can use replace() in first place to turn all of them into a unique character and then split it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
"half-attained".split("-")  # ["half", "attained"]
```

Works fine. Read the docs next time.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` splits string from separator characters and help you to get rid of those.

```
print("please-split-me".split("-")) 
# ["please" , "split" , "me"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create an array or just another string with both words? Can you show your expected output?

You might simply need: `test_list.replace('-', ' ')`