# How do you split a string after a symbol in python?

Tags: python, split, sympy

```
import sympy
equation = input('Enter an equation: ')
a = equation.split(('=') or ('<') or ('>') or ('<=') or ('>=') or ('==') or ('!='))[0:2]
b = sympify(a[0])
c = sympify(a[1])
d = simplify(b - c)
print('This is the equation simplified: ' + str(d))
```

I want to split the equation in two parts when one of the symbols (=,<,>,>=,<=,==,!=) appear, but in this code it only works when the '=' sign is the symbol.

Comment: The boolean value of non-empty strings such as ``'='`` is always true. ``'=' or ...`` always evaluates to ``'='``.

Comment: Look into split with regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.split

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python

Comment: could you please tell me how I should change my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be like that:

```
import re        #<--- add this
import sympy


equation = input('Enter an equation: ')
a = re.split(r'[=|<|>|<=|>=|==]', equation)[0:2]   #<--- only change this

b = sympify(a[0])
c = sympify(a[1])
d = simplify(b - c)
print('This is the equation simplified: ' + str(d))
```