# split string into sentences everytime there is punctuation, with punctuation?

Tags: python

I would like to split a string into separate sentences in a list.

example:

```
string = "Hey! How are you today? I am fine."
```

output should be:

> ["Hey!", "How are you today?", "I am fine."]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a built-in regular expression library.

```
import re
string = "Hey! How are you today? I am fine."
output = re.findall(".*?[.!\?]", string)

output>> ['Hey!', ' How are you today?', ' I am fine.']
```

Update:

You may use `split()` method but it'll not return the character used for splitting.

```
import re
string = "Hey! How are you today? I am fine."
output = re.split("!|?", string)
output>> ['Hey', ' How are you today', ' I am fine.']
```

If this works for you, you can use `replace()` and `split()`.

```
string = "Hey! How are you today? I am fine."
output = string.replace("!", "?").split("?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methode `split()`

```
import re
string = "Hey! How are you today? I am fine."
yourlist = re.split("!|?",string)
```

Comment: hello, I just tried this on vscode and the output was still a whole sentence, ['Hey! How are you today? I am fine.']

Comment: @KaramMohamed, have u tried the above code snippet ?

Comment: @rose forgot to mention you have to import re

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
>>> a='Beautiful, is; better*than\nugly'
>>> import re
>>> re.split('; |, |\*|\n',a)
['Beautiful', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'ugly']
```

[I find it in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this.  Just create your own generator:

```
def split_punc(text):
    punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
    # Alternatively, can use:
    # from string import punctuation
    j = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(text):
        if x in punctuation:
            yield text[j:i+1]
            j = i + 1
    return text[j:i+1]
```

Usage:

```
list(split_punc(string))
# ['Hey!', ' How are you today?', ' I am fine.']
```