# Split string by multiple delimiters, ignore repeating delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a string that has multiple delimiters which may be repeating.

Input string:
"-abc,-def,ghi-jkl,mno"

Expected return:
["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"]

I've tried

```
re.split(",|-", string)
```

But the return is:

```
['', 'abc', '', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
```

Comment: I think you want to use a quantifier `[,-]+` or match instead of split

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Comment: No, it does not answer *this* question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'[^-,]+', string)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/6YqBg9/1)

Python code:

```
import re
regex = r"[^,-]+"
string = "-abc,-def,ghi-jkl,mno"
print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

Result: `['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the result like this

```
>>> list(filter(len, re.split(r"[,|-]+", s)))
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
```