# How to split a string on variable separator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have complex number in the form of a string

x = `1+3j`

Using the `split()` method of strings , I want to break it into the real and imaginary parts.

**What I tried** :
I used the `+` as a separator of the string and got the real and imaginary values.

**Problem**: The complex number can also be`3-7j` , I that case , `split()` fails as the string does not have a `+`.

What a want is that the `split()` should split the string when it encounters either `+` or `-`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Comment: @RvdK , I saw it , But in my case I have to ignore the `+` and `-` if it occurs in the beginning or the end. Example `-3+5j`

Comment: How could `+` and `-` occur at the end?

Comment: @GZ0 , In the example , `x = -3+5j` if I use `re.split('-|+' , x)` (as mentioned in the link by @RvdK), then the split would be ['3', '5j'] . That is ,  the real part lost its `-` sign which I dont want

Comment: @NeoNØVÅ7 That is an occurence at the beginning, not the end. You comment says "in the beginning or the end". So I was wondering what that refers to.

Comment: @GZ0 ooops . Ignore that, I cant edit it now since I already commented after that

Comment: @NeoNØVÅ7 Is `3+-2j` a valid input?

Comment: @GZ0 , Ya it could be . but for the time being , your comment on x.real  an x.imag does the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
import numpy as np
y=complex(x)
xr,xi=np.real(y),np.imag(y)
```

I don't know if you want to keep them as strings, but if you do, just add str() around np.real(y) and np.imag(y).

Note that it doesn't work with you have spaces within your string.

Comment: No need to use `numpy`. Just access the parts via `y.real` and `y.imag`.