# Split string into list by separate delimiters, but only by certain instances of said delimiters

Tags: python, list, split

I think what I'm trying to achieve is fairly common but I can't find reference for it on the internet; either that or I'm misphrasing what I'm trying to do.

This is the string I would like to split:

```
array_1:target:radec, 0:00:00.00, -90:00:00.0
```

I would like to split it by the first two colons (':'), and by the first comma & space (', '), such that I get

```
['array_1', 'target', 'radec', '0:00:00.00, -90:00:00.0']
```

I've tried to run `split()` with arguments twice on the original string, and it fails on the second `split()` because I'm trying to split something that's already a list. All the other answers I can find seem to focus on splitting the string by all instances of a delimiter, but I want the last field in the list `0:00:00.00, -90:00:00.0` to remain like it is.

Comment: You can use `re.split`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python).

Comment: @costaparas the issue I'm seeing here is that of the colons that I do & don't want to split by, none have spaces either before or after. Also the case with second comma-space ', ' ; maybe I can somehow use regex...

Comment: You can split twice, once by space and comma, later just split the first part by colons.

Comment: You would need to split on ',' then merge back the last two columns and split again the other elements of the array. You cannot run split again on the list but you can on list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split it by the first `", "` (using `maxsplit=1`), then the first element of the resulting list split by `":"`:

```
s = "array_1:target:radec, 0:00:00.00, -90:00:00.0"

temp = s.split(", ", maxsplit=1)
temp[0] = temp[0].split(":")
result = temp[0] + [temp[1]]
```

---

*The result:*

> ```
> ['array_1', 'target', 'radec', '0:00:00.00, -90:00:00.0']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
l1 = s.split()
l2 = l1[0].split(':') + l1[1:]
```

This will first split by whitespace separator, then split the first element (only) by a colon separator, and then join the lists. Result:

```
['array_1', 'target', 'radec,', '0:00:00.00,', '-90:00:00.0']
```

Comment: Technically, this would work in this *very specific* case, but it is in no way generic -- better to use one of the methods suggested in the duplicate post.

Comment: @costapars the problem is that he wants to split by colon in certain places and by whitespace in other places. So you can't solve this by using multiple separators (e.g. first splitting by whitespace and then by colon).

Comment: This works fairly well, but I'd like to not have the comma in the third list entry, and for the last two entries to be part of a single entry, i.e. '0:00:00.00, -90:00:00.0' and not '0:00:00.00,', '-90:00:00.0'. My apologies if I'm sounding a bit dense, I'm a beginner with this sort of thing.