# How to split a string by multiple punctuations with Python?

Tags: python, string, split, punctuation

```py
s = 'a,b,c d!e.f\ngood\tmorning&night'
delimiters = [',', '.', '!', '&', '', '\n', '\t']

s.split()
```

Can I split a string by all of `',', '.', '!', '&', ' ', '\n', '\t'`? Is it possible to specify multiple delimiters for `string.split()`? For example, how can I split `s` into

```py
['a','b','c','d','e','f','good','morning','night']
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you can use regex for this one. Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` to achieve this as:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'a,b,c d!e.f\ngood\tmorning&night'

>>> re.split('[?.,\n\t&! ]', s)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'good', 'morning', 'night']
```

---

If you are looking for a solution using `split()`, then here's a workaround:

```
>>> identifiers = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\n\t '

>>> "".join((' ' if c in identifiers else c for c in s)).split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'good', 'morning', 'night']
```

Here, I am replacing all the identifiers with a space `" "` in the string, and then splitting the string based on the space.

Comment: Thank you! I've only used `re.findall()` before, but this `re.split()` is great!