# How to use re.split() with a string of multiple delimiters

Tags: python, delimiter

I have the following string of delimiters:

`delimiters = " \t,;.?!-:@[](){}_*/"`

I want to use the re.split() method to split words in a list. I am doing this:

`new_word = re.split(' |,|\t|.|?|!|-|:|@|[|]|{|}|(|)|_|{|}|*|/',word)`

I don't understand which specific delimiters need the escape character before them.

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong? Note that `re` works with regular expressions, not just plain characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Comment: I think I am confused about which specific delimiters need the escape character

Comment: It seems like you want to split on word-boundaries, so would simply be splitting on `"\\b"`