# Python split function with multiple delimeters

Tags: python, split

Anyone help me with multiple delimeters for split function?
For instance, given a string `"#1(X,Y)"`, I want to use delimiters such
as `(, ',', )` to get a set like `('#1', 'X', 'Y')`

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You separate delimiters with a "|".

For example:

```
import re
test_string = "'X, Y; Z*W'"
re.split('; |, |\*|\n',test_string)
['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W']
```

Comment: I tried re.split('\\( | , |\\)', '#1(X,Y)') but failed

Comment: Another way would be to use sub and then split afterward.