# How to pass several separators in method ( .split(....) ) in Python [For two and more variables in one string]

Tags: python, string, methods, split, delimiter

```py
# Task - input: amount of students for three classes ; output: amount of required desks

import math

First_Class, Second_Class, Third_Class = input("Enter amount of students for each class : ").split(sep=",")
Amount_Of_Desks = math.ceil(int(First_Class) / 2) + math.ceil(int(Second_Class) / 2) + math.ceil(int(Third_Class) / 2)
print(f" Sum amount of required desks is : {Amount_Of_Desks}")
```

I wanna two separators in only one string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the separators to one separator with **replace** function before calling split function

```
import math

First_Class, Second_Class, Third_Class = input("Enter amount of students for each class : ").replace(';',',').split(sep=",")
Amount_Of_Desks = math.ceil(int(First_Class) / 2) + math.ceil(int(Second_Class) / 2) + math.ceil(int(Third_Class) / 2)
print(f" Sum amount of required desks is : {Amount_Of_Desks}")
```