# how should i use split in python for multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, split

How can I split a string like `"five 6 seven, eight!nine"` to have only words? I mean remove everything and count the words? or in other words, how split a sentence with several delimiters? I should not use libraries.

```
def count_words(string):
    testlen=string.split( )
    
    return len(testlen)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Comment: What is a "library" here? A Python module that comes built-in with a normal Python installation, is that a library?

Comment: no, i should not  use import,

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this solution, even though there are duplicate answers spotted, because you say

1. Do not use any libraries (I assume even `re` is not allowed? )
2. You don't know what are the delimiters that might come

Example:

```
 def count_words(string):
        def ch(char):
            return char if char.isalnum() else " "
        return [ch(c) for c in string].count(" ")
```

It just replaces any non-alpha numeric to a space and then count the spaces. May be not a super pythonic one!

Comment: it is not working for count_words("test3four") ,it return 0 which suppose be 2.

Comment: well this idea was to consider only alphabets and numbers to be valid, so here its only 1. You should improvise the logic, as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Using re.split().
it is efficient and usually used method to split on multiple characters at once.

```
import re

string = "This, is a sample string"

print("initial string is : " + string) 

splitted_string = re.split(', |_|-|!', data)
```

I hope it can help. take a look at its documentation.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: we are not allowed to import,

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_words(string):
    alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"," "]
    for l in string:
        if l not in alphabet:
            string = string.replace(l, " ")#replacing non alphabit with space
            string = string.replace("  ", " ")#in case of 2 spaces resulted, replacing them with 1 space
    testlen = string.split(" ")
    print(testlen)
    return len(testlen)


string = "five 6 seven, eight!nine"
count_words(string)
```