# python - splitting string by characters

Tags: python, split

I have a string which looks as such:

```
my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
```

How do I get an array of values from the string?

```
[15,1,635,634,582,583]
```

Comment: Please share your thoughts/attempts for the solution with us to get better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be solved with a simple regex : `\d+`

```py
import re

my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
print([int(i.group()) for i in re.finditer(r'\d+', my_str)])
```

output:

```
[15, 1, 635, 634, 582, 583]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ")" and then split on "(":

```
[int(x) for x in my_str.replace(")", "").split("(")]
```

This list comprehension also converts the strings to ints.

Answer (score 0):

Given this particular input, one way to simplify the problem is to just grab continguous strings of digits, e.g. using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [int(''.join(group)) for dec, group in groupby(my_str, str.isdecimal) if dec]
[15, 1, 635, 634, 582, 583]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module:

```
import re
my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
my_str = re.findall(r"[\w']+", my_str)

for i in range(len(my_str)):
  my_str[i] = int(my_str[i])

print(my_str)
```

This will first split the list into Strings that are separated by special characters, then convert them to ints.

Alternatively, you can use a regular `.split()` function to split by `"("`, then remove the final `")"` with substring:

```
my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
my_str = my_str.split("(")
for i in range(len(my_str) - 1):
  my_str[i + 1] = int(my_str[i + 1][:-1])

my_str[0] = int(my_str[0])
print(my_str)
```

Output for both:

```
[15, 1, 635, 634, 582, 583]
```

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you have any further questions or need clarification :)

Comment: Curious about the `'` character in your regex. Is that a typo? Also whey `[\w]+` and not `\d+`?

Comment: It's not a typo. \d+ should work as well, but I just use [\w]+ when dealing with special characters in general

Comment: But you didn't use `[\w]+`, you have `[\w']+` with a `'`. What does the `'` do?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python). The preferred solution there was to replace all instances of one of the two delimiters with the other, e.g. by `new_str = my_str.replace(')', '(')`, which gives you a string where you have only one kind of brackest as delimiter. Then a `.split()` on that with that delimiter, and you get a list, which you can easily convert into an array. If you want the individual values as integers rather than strings you'll also need to cast them.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
new_str = my_str.replace("(", " ")
new_str = new_str.replace(")", " ")
my_arr = new_str.split()
my_arr = [int(num)for num in my_arr]
print(my_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a shorter way. Here is one:

```py
my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
my_str = my_str.replace(')(', ' ')
my_str = my_str.replace('(', ' ')
my_str = my_str.replace(')', ' ')
my_int_list = my_str.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

your str looks like this:

```
my_str = '15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)'
```

so replace ')' by space

```
mystr = mystr.replace(')'," ")
```

also replace '(' by space

```
mystr = mystr.replace(')'," ")
```

finally:

```
my_str = "15(1)(635)(634)(582)(583)"
mystr = my_str.replace(")", " ")
mystr = mystr.replace("(", " ")
mystr = [int(x) for x in mystr.split(" ") if x]
mystr
```