# How to split string using multiple characters in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am using Pandas and I would like to split the following strings:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = ['String1 - String2',
                     'This > That',
                     'One <-> Two'], columns = ["Value"])
```

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | String1 - String2 |
| 1 | String1 > String2 |
| 2 | One <-> Two |

The string splitter could be `-` or `>`. How could I split the string such that I would get the following result:

| Index | Value | String1 | String2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | String1 - String2 | String1 | String2 |
| 1 | This > That | This | That |
| 2 | One <-> Two | One | Two |

Thanks in advance

Comment: try re.split instead also possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with regex `\s+` for spaces before separators `-` or `>`:

```
df[['String1','String2']] = df['Value'].str.split('\s+[->]\s+', expand=True)
print (df)
               Value  String1  String2
0  String1 - String2  String1  String2
1        This > That     This     That
```

Comment: Sorry it is possible that the splitter is `<->`. Would like to how could I add the new one on the regex? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Winston - change `[->]` to `[<->]`

Comment: Thanks I modifed the code, then I found that it now only works on `>` but not `<->` and `-` anymore.

Comment: @Winston - Can you try `df[['String1','String2']] = df['Value'].str.split('\s+[->]\s+|\s+<->\s+', expand=True)` ?