# Remove 1st and last character from file content in list imput

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, delimiter

I'm trying to get the start and end quotes from items `"1st name` and `8th name"` removed from following outputs:

A random Draw:

```
3rd name 7th name 5th name "1st name
```

An other random Draw:

```
7th name 8th name" 6th name 3rd name
```

Screenshot:

[image: Remove quotes]

My script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from random import sample

root = Tk()
root.title('Name Picker')
root.iconbitmap('c:/myguipython/table.ico')
root.geometry("400x400")



def pick():
    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/myguipython/", title="Open Text File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ))
    name = text_file
    name = name.replace("C:/myguipython/", "")
    name = name.replace(".txt", "")
    
    text_file = open(text_file, 'r')
    step1=text_file.read().split('\",\"')
    step2=[]
    for a in step1:
        step2.append(a)
    print(step2)
    
    entries_into_list = step2
    number_of_items = 2

    string_data = [str(data) for data in step2]

    rando = sample(string_data, number_of_items)
    rando1 = sample(string_data, number_of_items)

    my_text.delete(1.0, END)
    my_text.insert(INSERT, " ".join(rando + rando1))

topLabel = Label(root, text="Picked Names", font=("Helvetica", 24))
topLabel.pack(pady=20)
winButton = Button(root, text="pick names", font=("Helvetica", 24), command=pick)
winButton.pack(pady=20)
my_text = Text(root, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 18))
my_text.pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

The read file is a text file with following content:

```
"1st name","2nd name","3rd name","4th name","5th name","6th name","7th name","8th name"
```

I've used the split command in line

`step1=text_file.read().split('\",\"')`

to remove `","` instances following idea from [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998688/10789707) and testing idea from [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7215696/10789707)
without success.

When random picks include the 1st or last item the open and end quotes show up.

How to remove them? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `step1 = text_file.read().strip('"').split('","')`

Comment: Great thanks that works fine.  Want to make it an answer? I'll check it!  Be well!

Comment: Pretty sure that this is duplicate question and it will be closed soon. Btw, if you have comma-separated file format, `csv` module should be handy.

Comment: Ok thanks for the idea, I'll look into that next.  I searched a while in SO search bar and google before but couldn't think of the handy strip workaround. Thanks again!