# How to select last group by text sub-strings

Tags: python, split

I have a list of characters:

```
groups = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

And I have a list of words:

```
strings = ['testing', 'tested', 'fisherman', 'sandals', 'name']
```

1. I need to split the words based on the characters mentioned in the groups list.
   The word "tested" can be grouped as "t + est + ed"
2. Select the last group. So 'ed' in this case should be selected and only 'd' returned, because 'e' is already known.

```
expected={'testing':'ng', 'tested':'d', 'fisherman':'n', 'sandals':'ls', 'name':''}
```

If there is only 'e' then I can write:

```
'tested'.split('e')[-1]
```

But not sure how to check other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
groups = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
pat = "|".join(groups)
strings = ['testing', 'tested', 'fisherman', 'sandals', 'name']
d = {s: re.split(pat, s)[-1] for s in strings}
```

This gives `{'testing': 'ng', 'tested': 'd', 'fisherman': 'n', 'sandals': 'ls', 'name': ''}`. Basically just following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
import re    

groups = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
strings = ['testing', 'tested', 'fisherman', 'sandals', 'name']

pat = "".join(groups)  # "aeiou"
expected = {s: re.search(f"[^{pat}]*$", s).group(0) for s in strings}
# {'testing': 'ng', 'tested': 'd', 'fisherman': 'n', 'sandals': 'ls', 'name': ''}
```

- `[^{pat}]*`: *zero or more* (*) of *not* (^) any of `pat`
- `$`: before the end of the word

If you want to implement this yourself:

```
def suffix(s, chars):
    for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
        if s[i] in chars:
            return s[i+1:]
    return s
 
>>> suffix("tested", "aeiou")
'd'
>>> suffix("testing", "aeiou")
'ng'
>>> suffix("name", "aeiou")
''
>>> {s: suffix(s, groups) for s in strings}
{'testing': 'ng', 'tested': 'd', 'fisherman': 'n', 'sandals': 'ls', 'name': ''}
```