# is there a way to join two dataframes with python when only parts of the column values are equal

Tags: python, csv, merge

i have dataframes with name columns, and i would like to match these when people with more than one name match for one name at least, e.g **john** should match **john-paul**.

my approach using this lambda notation did not work:

```
join = csv1[ csv2['Name'].apply(lambda title:
csv1['Name'].str.contains(title)).any(1) ]
```

seems like `contains` matches even if only one letter is same. using list transformation like this also does not work:

```
is_in_list = lambda search, list: search in list
join = csv1[ csv2['Name'].apply(lambda title: is_in_list (csv1['Name'], title.split(' ', '-'))).any(1) ]
```

results in error: `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

any idea, maybe not using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
csv1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'name': ['John', 'Peter Ringo', 'Paul'], 'surname': ['Novak', 'Dvorak','Newman']})
csv2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'name': ['John-Paul', 'Ringo', 'George'],'surname': ['Novak', 'Dvorak','Newman']})
join = csv1.set_index('surname').join(csv2.set_index('surname'), how='outer', lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2')
join['match'] = join.apply(lambda row: row['name_1'] in re.split(" |-",row['name_2']) or row['name_2'] in re.split(" |-",row['name_1']), axis=1)
```

https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-efficiently-compare-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe/

[Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

Comment: thank you, helped a lot to solve my problem. didn't know re so far.

Comment: Super. If you think my answer is work for you would you please mark it as use full?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend converting your csv files into dictionaries and then using for-loop instead of lambda:

```
for line_csv_1 in csv_1:
    name_csv_1 = line_csv_1['Name']

    for line_csv_2 in csv_2:
        name_csv_2 = line_csv_2['Name']

        if name_csv_1 in name_csv_2: # or name_csv_2 in name_csv_1
            # Write a new line at your join.csv file
```